# quantity increment button based on _qtyIncrements value

Tags: magento-1.8, quantity, product-page, qty-increment

I have different simple products each one have a **Qty** Increments .

I want to increment (+/-) each product by its Qty Increments on product page.
my increment code by 1 is :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.increment_qty').click(function() {
      var oldVal = jQuery(this).parent().find("input").val();


      if ( parseFloat(oldVal) >= 1 ) {
        var newVal = parseFloat(oldVal) + 1;
        jQuery(this).parent().find("input").val(newVal);
      }
    });

    jQuery('.decrement_qty').click(function() {
      var oldVal = jQuery(this).parent().find("input").val();
      if ( parseFloat(oldVal) >= 2 ) {
        var newVal = parseFloat(oldVal) - 1;
        jQuery(this).parent().find("input").val(newVal);
      }
    });
  });
//]]>
</script>
```

please help me

Comment: Please can you be more expolicit ? what do you mean by "I want to increment (+/-) each product by its Qty Increments on product page." ?

Comment: please you can take a look to    https://www.harmonieflorale.fr/produit/noeud-de-chaise-lycra-choco/   on qty block

Comment: Whats the problem? Seems to work!?!

Comment: I want to do like this website for quantity increment                                       
       NB:each product has its own quantity increment step

Answer (score 0):

You can do like below code:

You can get Qty Increments using the below code with Product Object:

```
$qtyIncrements = $productObj->getQtyIncrements();
```

If you are not getting the Qty Increments value then you need to load Product Inventory stock data. using the below code:

```
$productStockObj = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($productId);
$qtyIncrements = $productStockObj->getQtyIncrements();
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-4">
    <div class="details-qty qty shop-list">
        <span class="mini_decqty qty_btn btn btn-default" data-id="<?php echo $productId; ?>" data-field="item-<?php echo $productId; ?>-qty" data-type="minus" data-qty="<?php echo $qtyIncrements; ?>">-</span>
        <input type="number" size="4" class="item-qty" maxlength="12" id="item-<?php echo $productId; ?>-qty" value="<?php echo $qty; ?>" name="item-<?php echo $productId; ?>-qty" readonly="readonly">
        <span class="mini_incqty qty_btn btn btn-default" data-id="<?php echo $productId; ?>" data-field="item-<?php echo $itemId; ?>-qty" data-type="plus" data-qty="<?php echo $qtyIncrements; ?>">+</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS Code:**

```
$(document).delegate("span.qty_btn", "click", function(e) {
    fieldName = $(this).attr('data-field');
    var incQty = parseInt($(this).attr('data-qty'));
    dataId = $(this).attr('data-id');
    type = $(this).attr('data-type');
    var input = $("input[name='" + fieldName + "']");
    var currentVal = parseInt(input.val());
    if (type === 'minus') {
        if ((currentVal - incQty) < 1) {
            //Noting will happen as It leads to 0 qty here
        } else {
            input.val(currentVal - incQty).change();
        }
    } else if (type === 'plus') {
        input.val(currentVal + incQty).change();
    }
});
```

Comment: i dont want to increment by 1 , i want that each product will increment by its qty increment

Comment: for exmple 10 20 30 if my qty increments is 10

Comment: You can fetch that qty increment and add in span as `data-increment` preoperty like we are using `data-type` and in function can use this attribute value for increment and decrement

Comment: can I have more information about that please, I dont get how to do that exactly

Comment: I have updated my answer, hope this help

Comment: unfortunately it does not work for me

Comment: what error you are getting ?

Comment: not an error but nothing happens when i click on button + or -

Answer (score 0):

It also interests me.
I have Magento 2.2.6
but I can not find a solution.
I looked everywhere on the Internet, without success.
I also asked a question here:

[my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53060298/in-magento-2-2-6-in-addtocart-phtml-how-can-i-get-the-qty-increments)

Answer (score 0):

**You can try below code for increment and decrement qty in product detail page.**

```
<div>
  <a class="decrement_qty" href="javascript:void(0)">
    <img src="images/minus-qty.png" width="16" height="16" alt="&amp;ndash;" />
  </a>

  <input name="qty" size="4" value="1" />

  <a class="increment_qty" href="javascript:void(0)">
    <img src="images/plus-qty.png" width="16" height="16" alt="&amp;plus;" />
  </a>
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.increment_qty').click(function() {
      var oldVal = jQuery(this).parent().find("input").val();
      if ( parseFloat(oldVal) >= 1 ) {
        var newVal = parseFloat(oldVal) + 1;
        jQuery(this).parent().find("input").val(newVal);
      }
    });

    jQuery('.decrement_qty').click(function() {
      var oldVal = jQuery(this).parent().find("input").val();
      if ( parseFloat(oldVal) >= 2 ) {
        var newVal = parseFloat(oldVal) - 1;
        jQuery(this).parent().find("input").val(newVal);
      }
    });
  });
//]]>
</script>
```